# svn user defined config update

Tags: linux, svn, command-line

I have the following setup on a linux box in user home directory:

- ./svn.simple/hash#1
- ./svn.simple/hash#2

==

- hash#1 points to an old server: oldserver.com
- hash#2 points to current server. currserver.com

I need to alter the default server location for specific user to a new server. Apologies if terminology is off. How do I go about this? I investigate --relocate, but that seems for a specific working copy. All commands are run at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

A simple checkout from the new repository prompts if config is desired to be saved. If the response is 'yes' a new entry is added to ./svn.simple, saving all required config parameters.